# How to force FileSystemWatcher to wait till the file downloaded?

Tags: c#, multithreading, filesystemwatcher

I am downloading a file and want to execute the install only after the download is complete. How do I accomplish this? Seems like FileSystemWatcher onCreate event would do this but this happens in a different thread, is there a simple way to force the waiting part to happen in the same thread.

Code I have so far

```
 FileSystemWatcher w = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:/downloads");
 w.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 w.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileDownloaded);

 static void FileDownloaded(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
 {
    InstallMSI(e.FullPath);
 }
```

I looked at SynchronizingObject and WaitForChangedResult but didn't get a solid working sample.

Comment: How are you downloading the file? Sample code is nice.

Comment: downloading is being done in UI.. that code will make this question messy. I can only say that by the time this code is triggered, the download action has already started

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileSystemWatcher Work is Done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662893/filesystemwatcher-work-is-done)

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822175/filesystem-watcher-and-large-files

Comment: File system watcher monitors changes in Directory or files in directory, it is not monitor when you finish changes in a file. Your downloading code must handle when downloading finishes.

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath); 
while(IsFileLocked(fInfo)){
     Thread.Sleep(500);     
}
InstallMSI(e.FullPath);


static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException) {
        return true;
    }
    finally {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is the most straight forward solution but I don't want to use more thread.sleeps in my code. So I am using the other approach

Comment: I'm writing a console app and this worked perfectly. As I only have the one thread, I'm using this. +1.

Comment: Perhaps add a check for if the file exists?

Answer (score 5):

If you insist on using `FileSystemWatcher` you would probably have to account for the fact that a file of some size isn't created (uploaded) in one single operation. The filesystem is likely to produce 1 `created` and x `changed` events before the file is ready for use.

You could catch the `created` events and create new (dedicated) threads (unless you already have an ongoing thread for that file) in which you loop and periodically try to open the file exclusively. If you succeed, the file is ready.

Comment: This is absolutely true. I've been using this for a simple sFTP transfer program, and even a 17k file copied from root to test directory produced 1 created and 4 changed events.

Answer (score 2):

One technique would be to download to the temporary directory, and then *move* it into C:/downloads once it was complete.

Comment: How would I know if the download is complete, i.e when to trigger the move?

Comment: Depends on how you're downloading it. What does the code look like?

Comment: Do x when download complete. Well that's the question!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `WebClient` to download, you can use set the client's `DownloadFileCompleted` eventhandler.
If you do it this way you can also use `client.DownloadFileAsync()` to make it download asynchronously.